# Crash while uploading image using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm uploading an image using Alamofire like so..

**EDIT:** This is the edited code...

```
    for img in images {

    let url = "http:my url"
    let headers = [

           "Accept": "application/json",
           "Authorization": self.accessToken
       ]

if let imageData = (UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.6)) {
let parameters: [String: String]  =
            [

                  "seller_id": "\(self.mySellerId)",
                 "offline_id": self.prodID,
                 "is_default": "1",
                "sequence": "\(sequenceCount)"
           ]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: {(multipartFormData) in
               let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)

                    print(imageData)

                    multipartFormData.append (imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg", mimeType: "image / jpg")


                    for (key, value ) in parameters {
                        print(key,value)

                        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                    }
                }, to: url, method: .post, headers: headers)
                { (result) in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let upload, _,_ ):


                        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                            UILabel().text = "\((progress.fractionCompleted * 100)) %"
                            print (progress.fractionCompleted * 100)

                        })
                        upload.responseJSON { response in

                            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                                print(JSON)
                            }else{
                                print("Error")
                            }
                        }
                    case .failure(let encodingError):
                        print(encodingError)
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

In the part `for (key, value) in parameters...` the for loop goes through all values. But when it reaches the image data part, it crashes saying `Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.Data' (0x10787b9f0) to 'Swift.String'`

What should be given instead so that the error can be fixed..?

Comment: When you for loop go into the key,value: `"product_image", imageData`, `value` is already a Data object. Don't need to do convert it into `Data`, and it's not a String, so you `as! String` make it crashs. Instead, check the class of the `value`, if it's a `Data`, just append it as such, if it's a String, convert it with `data(using:)`, etc.

Comment: oh..ok. @ Larme If you won't mind could you just put it up in code...?

Comment: `if let v = value as? Data {multipartFormData.append(v, withName: key)} else {//It's a String, at least we hope so, do  as you already did)}`

Comment: Just remove this `"product_image": imageData` from your parameters data. It is not required in your due to available in multipart.

Comment: ok..I'll try...

Answer (score 0):

You are casting all values from `parameters` dictionary as `String`'s, first entry in dictionary is `"product_image"` and it has imageData as value and that is of type `Data`.

I would do this, no more force casting.

```
for (key, value) in parameters {
    if let v = value as? String, let valueAsData = v.data(using: .utf8) {
        multipartFormData.append(valueAsData, withName: key )
    }
}
```

You could also check if value is already `Data` type and just add it as well like:

```
for (key, value) in parameters {
    var dataToAppend: Data?
    if let data = value as? Data {
        dataToAppend = data
    } else if let v = value as? String, let valueAsData = v.data(using: .utf8) {
        dataToAppend = valueAsData
    }

    if let d = dataToAppend {
        multipartFormData.append(d, withName: key )
    }
}
```

Comment: ok @Ladislav. But will this take care of the string parameters also or just the data..?

Comment: The second method will append all five keys and values:  "product_image", "seller_id", "offline_id", "is_default", "sequence".

Comment: But at this line `if let d = dataToAppen...`I get the error `Constant 'dataToAppend' used before being initialized`

Comment: My fault, updated the code, dataToAppend has to be var not let

Comment: No @Ladislav. Working on that only..still didn't work...:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169406/discussion-between-v-bw-and-ladislav).